# Move around table with attached legs

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture, self-assembly-furniture, placement

I have a table that has the legs drill-attached to the surface. The surface and the whole table is quite heavy.
What is the best way to move the table around a room if
1) it is not very easy to lift up and carry around
2) pushing it could be risky for the attached legs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is friction of the legs against the floor, you can get some of these furniture sliders.  They will take that pressure off of the legs and allow you to push/pull the table without putting excess strain a the base of the legs.  This is, however, assuming that you can lift at least one corner of the table at a time just barely enough to get one of these under there.

[image: furniture sliders]

Comment: Which kind of stores sell these?

Comment: @Jim you should be able to find them at home department stores, on Amazon, or even some Walmarts have them.

Comment: Yes I would think friction would be the problem that could detach the legs off

Comment: Are they meant for solid floor or carpet or both?

Comment: @Jim I've used them both on Carpet and hardwood/linoleum before.  Basically any finished indoor surface should be fine,  You know, just not rough/unfinished concrete, gravel, grass, etc.  The bottoms of the pads are smooth so they'll just slide over any other forgiving surface.

Comment: +1 There are carpetlike covers for those to use on smooth surfaces and avoid scratching if some grit gets caught underneath.